# Variable gets "Undefined" in JQUERY Function

Tags: jquery

i am new to webdevelopment and atm i am trying to build a function which handels all different buttons on my Page (to call php code by post). 
It works fine without the switch/case (or if/else) but as soon as i try to dynamically "load" parameters for Post action it does not work properly anymore. It actually works, when i press the button a 2nd time which looks very strange to me :-). The problem is that button_id suddenly shows as "undefined" 
Could you give me a little advice please?

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".btn").click(function()
{
    button_id = $(this).attr("id");
    switch ($(this).attr("id"))
    {
        case "ZXY" :
           php_func_name =  "ABC"
           php_id = "DEF"
           break;

        case "XYZ" :
           php_func_name = "HIJ"
           php_id = "KLM"
           break;
    }

    $('#' + button_id).click(function() {
        $.post("php_functions.php", {
            method: php_func_name,
            id: php_id
        }, function(data) {
      $("#test").html(data);
      alert (data);
        });
    });

}); 
});
```

Comment: Where did you get the "undefined" value for button_id ?   By the way, consider changing this line:  `button_id = $(this).attr("id");`  to  `var button_id = $(this).attr("id");` .  Without the **var** , it adds button_id to the global `window` object so you are actually setting `window.button_id` . It's usually not what you want and can lead to bugs.  Consider adding another line after it, to define these vars also:  `var php_func_name, php_id;` . So these variables also remain local and don't get added to `window`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are changing the function for the `button.click`. As you do not know your HTML code, I would store the `php_func_name` and `php_id` data into `data-` attributes in the button:

```
<button id="ZXY" class="btn" data-funcname="ABC" data-id="DEF"></button>
<button id="XYZ" class="btn" data-funcname="HIJ" data-id="KLM"></button>
```

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.btn').click(function() {
        $.post("php_functions.php", {
            method: $(this).data('funcname'),
            id: $(this).data('id')
        }, function(data) {
            $("#test").html(data);
            alert (data);
        });
    });
}
```